Infinite rooted binary tree with additional horizontal edges
I have encoutered an infinite rooted binary tree with additional horizontal edges connecting every pair of adjacent vertices, i.e. there is an edge between 0 and 1, 00 and 01, 01 and 10, 10 and 11...
It seems that this graph is a well-known object and has been studied already, but I am not able to trace it.
I would like to know its name, if it has one. Or suggestions how to find information on it. Alternitavely I would like to know a formula of a geodesic distance for an arbitrary pair of vertices in the graph, with the metric being the standard path metric.
p.s. now I can add the picture of the graph:

For the distance in the graph, take any two vertices $x$ and $y$, with their labels as binary strings of length $|x|=m$ and $|y|=n$. Note that each layer consists of only same length binary strings, $|x_{10}-y_{10}|$. If $m=n$, then the distance is simply the decimal equivalent of $x-y$. If $m<n$, then you first go up from $y$ to the level of $x$ via parents (say $y'$), and then move horizontally to $x$. Note that $y'$ is just $y$ restricted to it's first $m$ bits. Then the distance is $(n-m)+|y'{10}-x{10}|$.
That said, I don't know what this graph is called though.

Your formulation is vague. Do the names you use like “01” and “11” encode the paths from the root to the nodes, where “0” means essentially, “take the left-hand child” and “1” means “take the right-hand child”? If so, then how do you name the root? And what do you mean by “adjacent”? Is it “at Hamming distance of exactly 1”?

What makes you think that the graph is well known?

@PaulTanenbaum I believe they are taking the standard binary tree, where the root is labelled by the empty string, and the left child of a node is labelled by the node's label concatenated by 0, and the right child is labelled by the node's label concatenated by 1 (Their example suggests this standard definition). And they add edges between two nodes of same length labels if their labels have a difference of absolute value 1.

Edit to my calculation comment, somehow the distance $|x_{10}-y_{10}|$ got misplaced; it should be after "decimal equivalent of x-y".

Let $x$ and $y$ be two points such that $x$ is below or at the same level as $y$. Let $x’$ be the parent of $x$ at the same level of $y$. Note that $x’$ is uniquely determined by this definition. Then,
$$
d(x,y) = d(x,x’) + d(x’,y).
$$
To see this, first it is clear that you must take $d(x,x’)$ vertical steps from $x$ to even get to the same level as $y$, which explains the first term. For the second term, the number of horizontal steps increases or remains same, but doesn’t decrease, as one goes lower in the tree. So the minimal number of horizontal steps is achieved at the upper point, which is $y$.
More concretely, let $\ell(x)$ be the length of the binary string $x$, and $n(x)$ be the nonnegative integer whose binary representation is $x$. Then,
$$
d(x,y) = \ell(x) - \ell(y) + \left|n(y) - \left\lfloor \frac{n(x)}{2^{\ell(x)-\ell(y)}}\right\rfloor\right|,
$$
